# Convert a 4D array to 3D in Python by merging the months and years columns

Tags: python, reshape

I have a 4D array that has two spatial directions, a month column and a year column. It gives a scalar value at each spatial point and for each month. I want to reshape this array to be 3D so that instead of the value being defined as x, y, month, year, it is just defined as x, y, month, where now the month column runs from 1-36 say with no year column instead of 1-12 with a year column of 1-3. How would I do this in Python? Thanks!

Comment: Post the code you tried so far and some samples of data

Comment: Please give some details. Currently this question is *unclear* or *too broad* and could be closed for those reasons.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  For this problem, we need at least the code so far and the best attempt you've made at the problem, plus the output you have from this.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is to code the new column something like:

```
new_month = old_month + 12*(old_year-1)
```

This translates your 3-year scale into a continuum of months numbered 1-36.  I can't show you how to code this, because (1) you haven't given us reference code, so I have little idea how your 4D array is structured; (2) As I *hope* you've read in the help documentation, we're not a coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column with values of `(year-1)*12+month` then discard or ignore your year and month columns.  *Details depend on exactly how your data is currently structured if it is a numpy array this would be 2 lines of code!*